# Oracle Application Express - Table View Not Ordered

Tags: oracle

I had created a table; however, every time I insert a row the data does not show up in the order I inserted, any reasons why?

For example,

I inserted rep 20 with all its needed info and so forth, then rep 30, and rep 40.

But the order comes out like this

```
30
40
20
```

as opposed to

```
20
30
40
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SELECT * FROM REP;  It works fine in Access and everything shows up in order but not in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

> *does not show up in the order I inserted*

Rows in a relational database do **NOT** have any "order". Think of them as balls in a basket.

The only (*really*: the **only**) way you can guarantee an order when selecting data is to use an `order by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results of your `SELECT` to be in a certain order, you must include an `ORDER BY` clause.  Without `ORDER BY`, the results can be in *any* order; it doesn't even need to be in a consistent order.

Assuming that your `REP` table has a column called `id`, your query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM REP ORDER BY id
```